# How do I support TLS 1.x only (in my webservice)?

Tags: delphi, ssl, openssl, delphi-xe2, indy

I'm trying to control what TLS/SSL protocols are supported for a HTTPS connections to my webservice, by using a `TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL` component and setting its `SSLOptions.Method` and `SSLOptions.SSLVersions` properties (as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36146053/512728)).

The default is Method `sslvTLSv1` and SSLVersions `[sslvTLSv1]` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22118046/512728) for the relations between Method and SSLVersions):

[image]

I use nmap with the `ssl-enum-ciphers.nse` script from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/763908/141909) to check what is actually available, and get this script output:

```
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.0:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_IDEA_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|     warnings:
|       Ciphersuite uses MD5 for message integrity
|       Weak certificate signature: SHA1
|_  least strength: C
```

But TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 are missing.

If I set Method to `sslvSSLv23` ("*a wildcard that allows dynamic version negotiation in cases where client and server support different SSL/TLS versions. It allows them to figure out and use the highest version common to both parties*" ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27198773/512728))) I see `sslvSSLv2`and `sslvSSLv3` become active.
But I do not want SSL 2.0 (deprecated/prohibited in 2011 by RFC 6176) and 3.0 (deprecated in June 2015 by RFC 7568) support ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)).
I cannot subtract both `sslvTLSv2` and `sslvTLSv3` from the set generated by method `sslvSSLv23`: we revert to the default configuration where only TLS 1.0 is supported.

Note that if I 'only' leave out `sslvTLSv2` (Method is `sslvSSLv23` and SSLVersions is `[sslvSSLv3,sslvTLSv1]`), nmap tells me:

```
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   SSLv3:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_IDEA_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|     warnings:
|       CBC-mode cipher in SSLv3 (CVE-2014-3566)
|       Ciphersuite uses MD5 for message integrity
|       Weak certificate signature: SHA1
|   TLSv1.0:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_IDEA_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|     warnings:
|       Ciphersuite uses MD5 for message integrity
|       Weak certificate signature: SHA1
|   TLSv1.1:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_IDEA_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|     warnings:
|       Ciphersuite uses MD5 for message integrity
|       Weak certificate signature: SHA1
|       Weak cipher RC4 in TLSv1.1 or newer not needed for BEAST mitigation
|   TLSv1.2:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_IDEA_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|     warnings:
|       Ciphersuite uses MD5 for message integrity
|       Weak certificate signature: SHA1
|       Weak cipher RC4 in TLSv1.1 or newer not needed for BEAST mitigation
|_  least strength: C
```

**What can I do so that only all TLS 1.x versions are supported?**

This is Delphi XE2 with Indy 10.5.8.0, running on Win7, tested with OpenSSL 1.02f. With OpenSSL 1.02g I get [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35895377/openssl-1-0-2-g-update-breaks-my-delphi-app), we are not yet ready for our update to Delphi Seattle (Update 1) where this is solved in the Indy code.

Additional notes:

- Should I drop TLS 1.0 support as well?
- `SSLOptions.Mode` is still at the default `sslmUnassigned`, I want to look at that later.
- Note that the nmap script only tests SSLv3/TLS versions, not SSLv2. I used [SSLScan](https://superuser.com/a/121572/141909) in addition, and this shows that if I leave out `sslvTLSv3` only, SSL2 is indeed still enabled ;-(
- Forget the info about weak ciphers, that's the next thing to tackle ;-)
- I am actually unable to do an nmap test if I run my webservice in the Delphi IDE, this gives all kinds of runtime errors (that do not surface if I run the executable). Maybe these are supposed to happen because the nmap script is firing off all kinds of tests?

```
    EIdOSSLAcceptError 'Error accepting connection with SSL. EOF was observed that violates the protocol.'
    EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError in ssl3_get_client_hello:no shared cipher
    EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError in ssl3_get_client_hello:wrong version number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 are missing.

Right, because if you set the `Method` to `sslvTLSv1`, Indy will only use TLS 1.0 specifically.

Your screenshot of the Object Inspector clearly shows that you are using a version of Indy that does not support TLS 1.1+ (if you were, there would be `sslvTLSv1_1` and `sslvTLSv1_2` options available in the `SSLVersions` property).

> Note that if I 'only' leave out sslvTLSv2 (Method is sslvSSLv23 and SSLVersions is [sslvSSLv3,sslvTLSv1]), nmap tells me:

When the `Method` is `sslvSSLv23`, Indy merely disables unwanted SSL/TLS versions, in this case SSLv2.  You are clearly using a version of the OpenSSL library that supports TLS 1.1+.  So, because your Indy version does not support TLS 1.1+, it is not disabling them.  They are enabled by default.  Since you are not disabling TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1+ get left implicitly enabled by OpenSSL itself.

> What can I do so that only all TLS 1.x versions are supported?

This is a little bit of an odd workaround, but you can set the `SSLVersions` to `[sslvSSLv23,sslvTLSv1]`.  That will set the `Method` to `sslvSSLv23` and remove `sslvSSLv23` from the `SSLVersions`.  This way, Indy will use the SSLv23 wildcard and disable SSLv2 and SSLv3, leaving TLS 1.0+ enabled.

Unfortunately, you cannot really make this configuration in the Object Inspector at design-time.  Well, you can (enable just `sslvTLSv1` first, and then enable `ssvSSLv23` afterwards), but it won't be saved in the DFM correctly (the `SSLVersions` will be omitted since `[sslvTLSv1]` is the default value), and will thus end up re-enabling SSLv2 and SSLv3 at run-time.  To avoid that, you will have to assign the `SSLVersions` in code at run-time, before activating your server:

```
IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvSSLv23,sslvTLSv1];
```

Otherwise, the alternative is to upgrade to an up-to-date version of Indy that natively supports TLS 1.1+, then you can just set the `SSLVersions` to `[sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2]` (at run-time or design-time) and move on.

Comment: Thanks Remy, this works. Luckily I was already doing everything at run-time. We are also working on upgrading everything from XE2 to Seattle in the near future.