# How do I support TLS 1.1 and 1.2 only (in my webservice)?

Tags: delphi, ssl, openssl, indy, delphi-10-seattle

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36333400/how-do-i-support-tls-1-x-only-in-my-webservice) I asked about limiting the available SSL/TLS protocols for my webservice under Delphi XE2.
By using a `TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL` component and setting its `SSLOptions.SSLVersions` properties to `[sslvSSLv23,sslvTLSv1]` I was able to limit he available protocols to TLS 1.x.

Now, after upgrading to Delphi Seattle Upgrade 1, I wanted to further limit this to TLS 1.1 and 1.2 only:

```
LIOHandleSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2];
```

But this does not work at all. When trying to connect I get a

```
exception class EidOSSLUnderlying CryptoError with message
'Error accepting connection with SSL. error: 140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol'
```

and

```
Error connecting with SSL
EOF was observed that violates the protocol
```

What is going on here? How to fix it?

Notes:

- Tested with OpenSSL 1.02f and 1.02h
- Setting the 'old' combination `[sslvSSLv23,sslvTLSv1]` works
- Including TLS 1.0 works as well: `[sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would personally just keep the SSLVersion to its default and use `SSLOptions.CipherList` instead to limit SSL using only known [secure ciphers](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS):

```
LIOHandleSSL.SSLOptions.CipherList := 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256';
```

This should disable older SSL versions implicitly because these do not support the specified ciphers AFAIK.

Note that OpenSSL 1.0.2g+ disables SSLv3 by default, unless one explicitly activates it during compilation.

Comment: ps. `sslvSSLv23` is the "Don't care" method that supports *all* SSL versions compiled into OpenSSL.

Comment: Smart idea. Note that I still have to specify `LIOHandleSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2];` (*or* `sslvSSLv23`) because the default is `sslvTLSv1` *only*. Since a) we recommend our users to use the latest OpenSSL (currently 1.02h) - meaning SSL 2/3 are disabled and b) we still need to support Android 4 I use the *Intermediate compatibility* list from your link without the SSL3 ciphers. That leaves 18 (prelimary tests show only 8, but that's another story related to Indy not supporting everything - e.g. https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=115075)

Comment: Specifying multiple versions in the `SSLVersions` property causes Indy to use `sslvSSLv23` internally and disable any versions that are not specified. Specifying `[sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2]` should work just fine, provided you are using an *up-to-date* version of Indy (Seattle does not ship with the latest) and OpenSSL.  There have been updates to Indy's handling of OpenSSL 1.0.2g+ after Seattle was released.